# How to Ignore RequiresValidation when null

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a requirement to skip validation when my list is empty and consider validation if list have values

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 99, groups = RequiresValidation.class)
  private List<@Valid MyInfo> myInf;
```

I don't want this size validation to be executed when my list is null. any help is appreciated.

I'm using javax.validation.constraints.Size library to check the validations,

Comment: Could you add some info of what you tried, what libraries you're using, maybe any errors you get? There isn't really enough context here to answer the question.

Comment: Are you sure this is what happens? I'm reading the @Size interface documentation and it says `null elements are considered valid.`